# Keep recieving: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int' from python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that adds up the cost of chicken feed after you have chosen it and keeps giving me the type error for "NoneType" and "int"

I am new to Python an have no idea what to do to fix it

```
def printMenu():
    print("Choose your type of chook food: ")
    print("A. Display Chook Food Types")
    print("B. Calculate total cost of the selected chook food")
    print("C. Exit the program")
    word = input("Enter A, B, C or D to proceed: ")
    if word == "A":
        print ("Choose the type of chook food: ")
        print ("A. 10kg Pellets")
        print ("B. 50kg Pellets")
        print ("C. 10kg Mash")
        print ("D. 50kg Mash")
        print ("E. 10kg Enhanced")
        print ("F. 50kg Enhanced")
        print ("G. Return to menu")
        food = input("Enter A, B, C, D, E or F, G: ")

        if food == "A":
            foodType() == smallPellets
            print ("You have chosen 10kg Pellets")
            return printMenu()

        elif food == "B":
            foodType() == largePellets
            print ("You have chosen 50kg Pellets")
            return printMenu()

        elif food == "C":
            foodType() == smallMash
            print ("You have chosen 10kg Mash")
            return printMenu()

        elif food == "D":
            foodType() == largeMash
            print ("You have chosen 50kg Mash")
            return printMenu()

        elif food == "E":
            foodType() == smallEnhanced
            print ("You have chosen 10kg Enhanced")
            return printMenu()
        elif food == "F":
            foodType() == largeEnhanced
            print ("You have chosen 50kg Enhanced")
            return printMenu()

        elif food == "G":
            return printMenu()

    elif word == "B":
        num1 = eval(input("Enter the amount you want to purchase: "))
        foodType() * num1 == totalCost
        print(totalCost)


    elif word == "C":
        exit()
    else:
        print ("You have entered the wrong key, try A, B, C or D")
        print ("")
    return printMenu()
```

I want to be able to chose the type of food and its specific price and when you enter the amount you need to buy it multiplys the price and gives you the answer

Comment: Please show the whole stacktrace of the error.

Comment: BTW, what do you think you're doing here: `foodType() == smallPellets`?

Comment: Need more info on the error.paste stack trace

Comment: What is `foodType()`? And what do you think `foodType() == <something>` does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can make out a few errors in your code, first of all "==" is the operator for *comparing* two values, "=" is the operator for *assigning* a value. So with "foodType () == something" you are not assigning anything, it would return either True or False, depending on what foodType () is.

Also when there are brackets behind something it means it's a function and you can't normally assign a value to a function, if you want to save multiple orders I would do something like this:

```
order = [] # create this list in the beginning of the function
# here come all your prints
if word == 'A':
    order.append("some type of food")
elif word == 'B':
    order.append("some type of food")
#...
else: # try to always include an else-statement for catching errors
    print("Food unknown")
# then, for price evaluation
totalPrice = 0
for i in range(len(order)):
    amount = int(input("How much", order[i], "do you want to buy?"))
    totalPrice += price(order[i]) * amount
    # price() is a function that returns the price of the given food type
```

This isn't the complete code, it's more of an outline, you'll have to piece it together yourself. Your error probably arises from `totalCost = foodType() * num1`, because, as already stated, foodType() is a function even though it shouldn't be.

Even if you don't make it a function something doesn't quite add up - you assign a string to foodType in 'A' and if you multiply it by num1 it wouldn't return the price, but the string num1 times like this:

```
>>> foodType = "pellets"
>>> num1 = 3
>>> print(foodType * num1)
>>> 'pelletspelletspellets'
```

That probably isn't what you want.

Feel free to ask if something isn't clear.